How to make a bootable stick for Ubuntu 24.04
I'm not familiar the with the latest Ubuntu version. When my download was completed I got the zip file, so I extracted the files and then got the below screenshot. How to make a bootable stick with these files?


Ubuntu is distributed as an ISO file, not a zip file or rar file. From where did you download it? Or is your Windows file browser 'thinking' it is a rar archive, even when it is actually an ISO file? -- Did you check with sha256sum that it was downloaded correctly? -- In Windows you can use the tool Rufus to make a USB boot drive from an Ubuntu ISO file.

I concur with @sudodus, your browser made the changes to the file according to its own rules (a nanny type of protection mode). You should not have extracted it; just reversed the change (likely rename) done by your unstated browser.  Your alternative is to use a download tool that doesn't try and nanny you (ie. only does exactly what you tell it to).  If you're using a corporate machine, the change could also be done by your enterprise network; so reverse whatever changes were made (checksum check as Sudodus said will detect if it was changed if you check the non-extracted file)

I already download latest ubuntu version from their offical website. I don't get any iso file in my folder. I don't lie. Ubuntu is gave me to zip file. I don't understand it. So when I do zip file and then I got the such as boot,EFI, install,pool..etc and folders.  I know ubuntu is offical distrubuted iso file version. What wrong with me. Please check my screenshoot above I provide.

It seems your Windows file browser 'thinks' it is a rar archive, even when it is actually an ISO file. (It is not your fault; let us blame Windows.) I suggest that you install and use Rufus to make a USB boot drive from the Ubuntu ISO file.

I see no .ZIP file at https://releases.ubuntu.com/24.04/  and only ISO files, or a link to a tarball (older format of ZIP file; but it's a tar.gz) for netboot installs.  Try a different browser that doesn't try and nanny (protect you from yourself) you. Your browser is probably downloading the ISO file and either renaming it (windows can do this if protection is on)  OR your windows is set to treat ISO files as archive/ZIP files.

Does this answer your question? What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?

I don't lie bro. I'm really stuck in download iso file. ubuntu zip file Please check my image. I switch to the another browser for download iso file. But when I download I got the zip file have been again. I dont have any ideas. So I switch to my phone and go the the  ubuntu official website, but unfortunately I got the zip file again

If you look at the download window top right of your display you can see it's attempting to download an ISO file...   Your system dealing it later as a .ZIP file is due to your OS setup/configuration or nanny protection tools running that are treating the ISO as a .zip file directly... ie. your issue is not what you download, but with your current OS whatever that is.. I suggest reading what @sudodus has already stated..  Don't use the windows file-browser, but just select the file by your ISO writing software as per ISO writing documentation for windows? (or whatever OS you're using)

I already know how to download and install ubuntu a right way and how to make bootable stick with rufus. But in that case, When I download I got the zip file iso file error. I dont lie. zip file

Look at the file-name, it shows clearly it's an iso file... if you're talking (or worrying) about the icon left of the balloon picture; that's a result of your window setup that has allowed the apps (winrar or whatever it is) deal with files of ISO type.. ie. your problem is your windows configuration which has been altered by someone, or a consequence of installing an app & allowing it to change your settings away from microsoft defaults

Are you think it cause by window configuration?. But I switched to my mobile phone and just download again. When I downlaod is complete I got the pure iso file. this file name end with .iso.   But when I copy .iso file to my computer and instantly it change to the zip file when I received. Please help me.

You no doubt have an ISO file on your system, however your windows config tells your system to treat files that end in .ISO as if they're a ZIP file.. This is due to a incorrect or bad association on your windows system (I see a winrar icon, it may have been done when [bad] defaults were accepted on install of winrar as many users don't read everything & adjust to make it perfect for your system). I'd recommend not using the windows explorer, but just open your ISO writing software & point it to the .ISO file on your disk  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

'Hello there! It appears that WinRAR is associated to ISO file, and that is why you decided to extract it.
If you want to make a bootable USB stick, please follow this: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview
You can use Rufus, it will be very simple. Basically you will download the application, open it, select your USB, select the ISO you download, start the process, and you will be done.

Yes, I know. I used other version of ubuntu such as 18 or 20.  When I download is completed I got the iso file. But in that latest version of ubuntu, I got the win rar file. What wrong with me. I already know to use link to make bootable stick. But in that case, I done my rar files I got the  I got the such as boot,EFI, install,pool..etc and folders. Please check my screenshoot above I provided.

I'd suggest you start off, by downloading the ISO-Image you want to use, in your case it's Ubuntu 22.04.
You can download the ISO-Image on the official Ubuntu page:
https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop
After that you can use Rufus to use that ISO-Image to create a bootable USB-stick. Just download Rufus from the official site, and don't forget to set the USB-Filesystem to FAT32 in Rufus while flashing the USB-stick.
I hope I was able to help you out.

Yes, I know how do I download and make bootable stick with rufus. But in that case when I download the iso file I got the zip file again. How to solve that. Please check this screenshoot. ubuntu error.  I try some of different method like switching different browser for download , switching my phone for download and get iso file. But in that case, I got the zip file only. Really stuck
